# C# Selenium Element Click can't find subsequent sub elements with same classname. What am I doing incorrect?

Tags: c#, selenium

**Given**

When page first loads and this statement is run :

`webdriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("TreeNode");`

I can easily find all those elements, but after clicking on one of them to get to the sublements, that same query doesn't show the new elements even though they are all using the same class.

How do I get Selenium to cough up the new elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the test program was not waiting long enough after the click.  I added an arbitrary wait and then all of the elements showed up.  Apparently, the test was moving much faster than the browser was.